# pagination twice click to get data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still new at react and currently I'm trying to create a pagination to get data list from my backend
my problem is i need to click the page button twice to get the data, i created a function to setstate and get data but i think it only run the setstate and the get data later after i click twice

```
 this.state = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 5,
  dataLength: '10',      
}

  render() {
    let links= []
    for (let i = 1; i <= (this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit); i++) {
        links.push(i)
}

    <h1>PAGE {this.state.page}</h1>
    { links.map((data, i) => {
    return <Button className='links' key={ i } onClick={() => this.setPage(data)}> { data }</Button>
      }) }

  setPage(data) {
   this.setState({ page: data })
   this.getData()
  }

  getData(){
   axios get localhost3000
 }
```

Comment: add this.getData() script.Is it API call function?

Comment: check in network tab if any API call is happening on first click

Comment: Can you share your other code too? It's very hard to figure out the problem from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Never create multiple logic functions on rendering methods. This will make your app become slow and even crashed

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
   contructor() {
     this.state = {
       page: 1,
       limit: 5,
       dataLength: '10',
       link: []      
     }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.paginationProcess()
   }

   setPage() {
      this.setState({ 
        page: data 
      }, () => { 
        this.getData() 
     });
   }

   paginationProcess() {
       let links= this.state.link;
       for (let i = 1; i <= (this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit); i++) {
         links.push(i)
       }
      this.setState({
        link: links
      })
   }

   render() {
     return (
        // ...
        { this.state.link.map((data, i) => {
          return <Button className='links' key={ i } onClick={() => this.setPage(data)}> { data }</Button>
        }) }
      )
   } 
}
```

Happy Hacking...
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this.getData()` as a callback to `setState` so it only triggers after the `setState` has finished

```
setPage(data) {
 this.setState({ page: data }, 
    () => { this.getData() }
  );
}
```

What's happening is that `this.getData()` is being called on your previous state.

I suggest adding the `this.getData()` function to your question